# Is it normal for Alluxio master to have verbose output dynamically

Tags: java, bigdata, netty, grpc, alluxio

I'm using `Alluxio` 2.0 to accelerate compute layer's performance.

When no query is performing, I found there are about verbose `netty` output appendding to `$Alluxio_home/logs/master.log`.

```
2019-11-25 10:26:32,141 DEBUG NettyServerHandler - {} {} HEADERS: streamId={} headers={} streamDependency={} weight={} exclusive={} padding={} endStream={}
2019-11-25 10:26:32,141 DEBUG NettyServerHandler - {} {} DATA: streamId={} padding={} endStream={} length={} bytes={}
```

Dozens of above message are appeneded to `master.log` each second. 
Is it a normal behavior? If sure, what's it used for? For heartbeat amoung components?

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause, leave this thread here for anyone who might encounter the same problem.

The `Alluxio` is using `gRPC` as its RPC framework and the latter is based on `netty`, the verbose output is actually from `netty`, check [this thread](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/3033) for details.

To disable the verbose output from Alluxio side, add below statement to `$Alluxio_home/conf/alluxio-site.properties`:

`log4j.logger.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler=OFF`

Note that modify `log4j.rootLogger` of `alluxio-propeties` can't disable this verbose output.